# Duvidas no myjson

Tags: javascript, json

Gostaria de utilizar esse codigo no site [myjson.com](http://myjson.com/) mas dá-me o erro `Error: Your JSON appears to be invalid.`. Como devo fazer?

```
[{        
    "imagem": '<a href="http://bit.ly/1r1QIF4" target="_blank">Clique aqui para ver o local</a>'
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O formato/sintaxe de JSON define que as chaves e valores têm de ser strings com aspas e não plicas. Assim precisas de escapar as aspas que estão no meio da string assim:

```
"<a href=\"http://bit.ly/1r1QIF4\" target=\"_blank\">Clique aqui para ver o local</a>"
```

**resultado**: http://myjson.com/51bzy

Podes também trocas as aspas dentro da string por plicas. Nesse caso fica assim:

```
"<a href='http://bit.ly/1r1QIF4' target='_blank'>Clique aqui para ver o local</a>"
```

e no site funciona também: https://api.myjson.com/bins/2w67y

Uma ferramenta que uso muito e que me indica erros no JSON é o http://jsonlint.com/, feito pelo próprio criador do formato JSON.

Comment: obrigado, mas ao utilizar `"<a href='http://bit.ly/1r1QIF4' target='_blank'>Clique aqui para ver o local</a>"` acabou virando `" \u003ca href=\"http://bit.ly/1r1QIF4\" target=\"_blank\" \u003e Clique aqui para ver o local \u003c/a\u003e"` e ai nao consegui utilizar. o que eu faço?

Comment: @NatanaelJunior ah, estou a ver. Usa então o primeiro exemplo ou usa `decodeURI(essaString);`

Comment: obrigado consegui.....